# How can I print an array of object in a GUI JPanel?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have array of object named "supermarkets" in every object there is String value called `Name` and method to return the value of the name called `get-name()`.
I want to print all the elements in the array using a GUI JPanel.
What can I use to print it?
This is what I want to print:

```
for (int i=0; i<supermarkets.length;i++){
       supermarkets[i].get-name();
}
```

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Do you want just simply text or do you want some kind of interaction, like mouse or keyboard interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a JOptionPane and more specifically a messageDialog which can be acheived by `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Params);` where params depend on the method you choose. Read the docs for more.

#### Example #1

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<supermarkets.length;i++){
    text.append("\n"+supermarkets[i].get-name());
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Available supermarkets:"+text.toString());
```

#### Example #2

**Example #1** is alright if the ammount of supermarkets is limited, but if it exeeds a specific number, the window will become so big that it wont fit in the screen. To prevent that from happening, here is an example where 4 supermarkets are displayed per line seperated by comma's

```
int supermarketsPerLine = 4;//The ammount of supermarkets displayed per line

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<supermarkets.length;i++){
    text.append(supermarkets[i].get-name()+", ");
    if(i%supermarketsPerLine == 0 && i>0) text.append("\n");
}
text.delete(text.length()-2, text.length()-1);// to remove the last comma (,) from the end of the list.     
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Available supermarkets:\n"+text.toString());
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: thax new info for me @fillpant

Comment: No problems! :) Glad i helped!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Create as many `JLabel`s as you need and set the text of each element in them.
2. Use `JList`.
3. Create a class which extends `JPanel` and override `paintComponent()`. Use `Graphics.drawString()`.

Of these, I think #2 is probably the best.

Comment: Or puting multiple lines in a single JLabel.

Comment: Good solutions, but there is no other solution?

Comment: @IbrahimRayis Yes, there are many more solutions. Most of them are even more complex than what I have listed here.